# How to provide my <App/> with data that is built differently on client and server renders and is needed by the <App/> and its thunks?

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, server-side-rendering, redux-toolkit

I have some data that is only defined in my `index.tsx` file, right before I render my `<App/>`. Once that data is defined, it does not change anymore. I need my `<App/>` to be aware of that data.

Other needs:

- Sometimes that data is needed inside a component (i.e: would be accessible via context and state)
- Sometimes that data is needed inside a redux thunk (i.e: would be accessible only via state, or parameter passed to the thunk)

For example:

**index.tsx**

```
const COUNTRY = getCountry(window.location);
```

**ssrApp.tsx (on server)**

```
const COUNTRY = getCountry(req.hostname);
```

My dilema is that I cannot export that data from the `index.tsx` or the `ssrApp.tsx` files, because they are 2 different files and one is for client and one is for server rendering. I also need to provide that data to my `<App/>`.

The easier route I guess would be to pass to the app via context. Like:

```
render(
  <SomeContext.Provider value={COUNTRY}>
    <App/>
  </SomeContext.Provider>
);
```

I started doing this, and it worked nicely for the most parts, but it broke when I started needing that data inside a thunk. AFAIK, thunks don't get ACCESS to the context. But they can access state (redux state).

So I created a redux state that I call `PRELOADED`, and I add that data to the store as a `preloaded` state value.

Something like:

```
configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    preloadedState: {
      PRELOADED: {
        COUNTRY: getCountry(window.location)
      }
    }
  });
```

It solves the "accessible to thunks" problem, but it creates other problems.

Because `@reduxjs/toolkit` demands you to initialize every state slice, even though you know for sure that that state will ALWAYS be preloaded.

```
const PRELOADED_SLICE = createSlice({
  name: "PRELOADED",
  initialState: getInitialState(),
  reducers: {
    SOME_ACTION(state, action: SOME_ACTION) {
      // DO SOMETHING
    }
  }
});
```

So you end up having to create a "dummy" `initialState`, because the real state will only be defined in run-time.

Anyway, the `PRELOADED` state approach seems to do the work so far. Is there a best practice to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is static data, right, so why not include it in a source file and import it to both index.tsc and ssrApp.tsx if they both need it.

Alternatively using your PRELOADED slice, why not just populate the getInitialState() with the data you need in the first place and have no Actions and a noop reducer in that slice?

I have a feeling your description `I have some data that is only defined in my index.tsx file, right before I render my <App/>.` actually means something other than static data.

Comment: It's not exactly static data. It's static from the `<App/>`'s point of view, but dynamic to the entry point `index.tsx` point of view. Just like the `window.location` and `req.url` examples. One gets the `hostname` from the `window.location`, because it's being rendered on client. And the other is using the `req` object on server. I cannot populate `getInitialState()` because that is done in the `createSlice()` call and it cannot access the `index.tsx` or the `ssrApp.tsx` files. I can only pre-populate using the `preloaded` of the `configureStore()` call, which is done on both client / server.

Comment: Why is that not just a React prop? https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: it could be. But it's hard to pass props 10 levels down. So I could instead use context. But `thunks` can't access context data, and sometimes they need it. That's why I moved it to Redux state. I could also pass that data to the `thunk` as a parameter though.

Comment: Yes assuming the thunk is invoked in the context of a UI component then it CAN get 'access' to Context data. I should have mentioned Context specifically as an alternative rather than just saying props when I meant 'isn't this just normal binding data to UI'.

Comment: It is called from a UI component, indeed. But the access you mean is for the thunk to get the data as a parameter from the call, right?